# Mongoose $match $in array created from request query is not working

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I don't know why it's not working while trying to do a match inside array of strings which comes from client's request query. This is what I've tried to do filter from my database

```
const serviceTypes = ["Hybrid", "Special", "Normal"];

if (req.query.serviceTypes) {
   serviceTypes = req.query.serviceTypes;
}
....

const packagesList = await PackagesList.aggregate([
....
// here I did an aggregation which works all fine if there is no req.query.serviceTypes
....

      {
        $match: {
          isActive: true,
          "packageService.serviceType": {
            $in: serviceTypes,  // I've also tried to directly feed `JSON.parse(req.query.serviceTypes)`
          },
        },
      },
```

What confuses me is it works well if I didn't send any request query in the header and I tried to see what it gets in my console and the output is all fine. i.e if I send this in the request `serviceTypes=['Hybrid', 'Normal']`

my `console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.serviceTypes));` output looks like

```
['Hybrid', 'Normal']
```

But the result is an empty array even though there exist a valid data in my database.

Comment: And another funny thing, this method works with `POST` method

Comment: Try deconstruction: 
[...req.query.serviceTypes]
Or Loadash: 
_.map(req.query.serviceTypes, _.clone);

Comment: @IsraelKouperman but what makes the difference if I still can do this in `req.body.serviceTypes`

Comment: Change `const` to `let` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: Are you not getting any `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable` when `if` statement is true?

Comment: No. There is no error at all but rather it responds with an Empty array

Comment: @Kirubel Can you try adding a `console.log` just after the `if` statement and make sure that the code below it is executing in both cases (When you pass query string and when not passing)

Comment: @Vishnu yes I've tried to see inside the `if` statement before it goes there and also after. In all scenarios I'm able to get the query parameter array value but the `$match` result is empty.

Comment: Please add the full code of your request.